# monodevelop gdb failed to set controlling terminal

Tags: ide, gdb, monodevelop

I looked this up on other stackoverflow questions and they said to uncheck the box that says run on external console. And I did that on both Run and Build settings in my Project Options. However it seems like i'm still using the external console and i get the following error:
[image]

I want to use gdb so i can step debug my program.
I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Another quick question: How do i get the error messages to output line numbers? Right now it only says the following:
[image]

Comment: Is it the code or monodevelop itself throwing this error? We cant tell without the code

Comment: It is the code. HTere are other errors msgs that follow after the System.NullReferenceException line telling me what functions to look for but without any line numbers. I'm refraining from posting the code because it's a project i'm working on with group of people. In addition, the code is huge and I don't even know where to start debuggin with the error because it's not specific enough

Comment: Ok. Well, SO has a great page on how to handle NREs. Also, start poking around in MonoDevelop options and look for something that could preventing line number output. I recommend use of the debugger for the NRE

Comment: oops, i uploaded the wrong picture. the first one is updated. I want to step debug it but i can't because i get the following error msg on gdb.

Comment: Hmm. You might need to try uninstalling and reinstalling things? Im not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error from gdb just means that gdb itself is not being run with a controlling terminal.  I think it is safe to just ignore this.